# Managed Grafana region availability

Tags: azure, azure-managed-grafana

I was wondering if Azure is planning to make Managed Grafana service available in any of the two Swiss Regions?
According to the documentation about service availability, there isn't anything planned yet for the near future.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/

Comment: Unfortunately Azure Managed Grafana is not currently available in either of the two Swiss regions. The supported regions for Azure Managed Grafana are listed in the "Supported regions" section of the "Azure Managed Grafana service reliability" article. If you need to use Managed Grafana in a different region, you can create your Azure Monitor workspace in any of the supported regions and use Managed Grafana in a different region than where you created your Azure Monitor workspace.

Comment: References:

-   [Azure Managed Grafana service reliability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/high-availability#zone-redundancy)
-   [Manage an Azure Monitor workspace - Frequently asked questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/azure-monitor-workspace-manage#frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: You can put a request in the MS forum regarding this.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

As per Azure Managed Grafana service reliability documentation, unfortunately Azure Managed Grafana is not currently available in either of the two Swiss regions. The supported regions for zone redundancy are East US, South Central US, West Europe, and Australia East.
[image]

The supported regions for Azure Managed Grafana are listed in the "[Supported regions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/?products=managed-grafana&regions=all)" section of the "Azure Managed Grafana service reliability" article. If you need to use Managed Grafana in a different region, you can create your Azure Monitor workspace in any of the supported regions and use Managed Grafana in a different region than where you created your Azure Monitor workspace.

You can put a request in the MS forum regarding this.

References:

- [Azure Managed Grafana service reliability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/high-availability#zone-redundancy)
- [Manage an Azure Monitor workspace - Frequently asked questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/azure-monitor-workspace-manage#frequently-asked-questions)